# How to show random product collection on category page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, catalog

How to override the default category product collection to show random products on the category page in Magento 2? Also, sort-by should be work when it selected. Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Below code in your **list.phtml** file,

```
$_productCollection = $_productCollection->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

Comment: I tried this but not working.